# Spark : how to tell spark to use local hadoop than its embedded hadoop?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I installed hadoop (v2.8) on my PC and it's running fine.

```
x:conf techlead$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.8.5
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 0b8464d75227fcee2c6e7f2410377b3d53d3d5f8
Compiled by jdu on 2018-09-10T03:32Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 9942ca5c745417c14e318835f420733
This command was run using /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.5.jar
```

And I installed Spark afterwards and configure it to use yarn, but when I start it, it's using its embedded hadoop :

```
20/09/28 00:26:33 INFO repl.SparkILoop: Created spark context..
Spark context available as sc.
20/09/28 00:26:33 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 1.2.1
20/09/28 00:26:33 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Inspected Hadoop version: 2.6.0
20/09/28 00:26:33 INFO client.ClientWrapper: Loaded org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.Hadoop23Shims for Hadoop version 2.6.0
```

I searched on Internet but not found the solution. Both hadoop and spark are running on my PC in single node mode, I want to tell spark to use the hadoop I installed on my PC (2.8.5) and not the embedded 2.6.0. I also noticed the scala version it used it's also not the same as what I installed on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is compiled with a specific version of Hadoop. Please see the [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.1/pom.xml#L123) "hadoop.version" line. If you want to use Spark with a different version, you will need to find the version of Spark that uses that version of Hadoop, or re-compile with the desired version.

Comment: Hi, my question is how to use the local Hadoop for Spark ? I can change the hadoop to the version Spark needs, but how I can point Spark to use this hadoop ?

Comment: My answer is basically saying "No" because Spark needs to be compiled with that version in order to be compatible.

Comment: So basically the version of hadoop on which Spark is compiled , if I understand correctly, has nothing to do with the actual hadoop version on my cluster ?? In this case, how I can assure that these two hadoop share the same underlying API ??

Comment: If you mean for Spark to be using the HDFS that is set up on the cluster, refer to: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#inheriting-hadoop-cluster-configuration